# How to check css class before running a script

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a web page interface that look like a Windows desktop.

My problem is that when I click on an app icon in the start menu I want to append that app icon in the task bar. Before it's appended I added class to that icon in the start menu to mark that this app is already opened, so if the app is already opened, the I don't want the new app icon to be appended in the task bar.

I used the code below but even then the class was added and the new icon in the task bar is still appended.

```js
$(".app_ico").on('click', function() {
  var checkClass = function() {
    var check = $(".app_ico").hasClass("luanched");
    if (check === true) {
      return (true);
    } else {
      return (false);
    }
  }
  checkClass();

  var appIcoId = $(this).attr("id");
  var appId = "#" + appIcoId.substring(4);

  if (checkClass() === false) {

    $(this).addClass("launched");
    $("" + appId).addClass("app_open");
    $(".taskbar").append("<div>A</div>");

  } else {
    $("" + appId).addClass("app_open");
  }
```

Comment: change     var check = $(".app_ico").hasClass("luanched");  in  var check = $(".app_ico").hasClass("launched");

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't understand what you mean.

Comment: wrong spelling of launched

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you set the class `launched`, yet check for `luanched`. Also, your logic can be improved. Your `checkClass()` function is entirely redundant, for example. Try this:

```
$(".app_ico").on('click', function() {
  $("#" + this.id.substring(4)).addClass("app_open");

  if (!$(this).hasClass("launched")) {    
     $(this).addClass("launched");
     $(".taskbar").append("<div>A</div>");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasClass`

```
if( $("selector").hasClass("calss") )
{
// if selector has class
} else{
// no chance

}
```